# How to set maxHeaderSize on Nuxtjs?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs

I'm having 431 issue on my nuxt app. The nuxt app is running on node 12. I read that node 12 is limiting maxHeaderSize to 8KB.

Is there any way to set maxHeaderSize from nuxt.config.js? I've read the  documentation but cannot find anything about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified the start script and it works fine:

before:
`"start": "nuxt start",`

become:
`"start": "NODE_OPTIONS='--max-http-header-size=16384' nuxt start",`

Comment: what if you deploy it on a server like nginx that only supports up to 8kb?

Comment: @Ifaruki You can override nginx max header size using
`client_header_buffer_size 16k;`
`large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;`. I'm currently not using nginx in font of my nuxt app so I can't tell it's really working or not.

Comment: I might be running into this right now with nginx ...